# Return records for which a corresponding record in the same table does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table where the [CloseDate] field uses a specific date to indicate ‘Open’ (1/1/1900), and any other date to indicate ‘Closed’.  There can be many ‘closed’ records for a given [task] field, and there should be an ‘Open’ record for tasks that are still valid (re-scheduled).  I am wanting to find where an ‘open’ record does not exist.  My concern is only with recent ‘Closed’ records not having a corresponding ‘Open’ record.

I have attempted many titles for this submission to find previously asked questions that fit with no success.

I use the following to find the ‘Closed’ records for which I want to discover where the [task] does not have a corresponding ‘Open’ record, but I fall short in how to modify the below to additionally filter out those that do have a corresponding ‘Open’ record.  I have been attempting to add a ‘Where Not Exists’ [CLOSEDATE] = Convert(datetime, '1900-01-01' ), but open to any solution.

```
SELECT a.[CLOSEDATE],a.[TASK]
FROM MyTable a
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT [TASK], Max([CLOSEDATE]) as MaxDate
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY [TASK]
) b ON a.[TASK] = b.[TASK] AND a.[CLOSEDATE] = MaxDate
WHERE a.[CLOSEDATE] >= DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Dale Arp, was my answer helpful? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your posted code does indeed work, you only need to extend it to exclude these tasks that have `1900/01/01` value in `ClosedDate` column.

I've used your code for conversion purpose, as I don't know how your data looks but I bet that you do :)

> [CLOSEDATE] = Convert(datetime, '1900-01-01' )

Extended code will look like this:

```
SELECT a.[CLOSEDATE],a.[TASK]
FROM MyTable a
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT [TASK], Max([CLOSEDATE]) as MaxDate
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY [TASK]
) b ON a.[TASK] = b.[TASK] AND a.[CLOSEDATE] = MaxDate
WHERE 
    a.[CLOSEDATE] >= DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM MyTable intbl
        WHERE 
            intbl.[TASK] = a.[TASK]
            AND intbl.[CLOSEDATE] = CONVERT(datetime, '1900-01-01')
        )
```

Note, that I only added following lines to your `WHERE` condition:

```
 NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM MyTable intbl
            WHERE 
                intbl.[TASK] = a.[TASK]
                AND intbl.[CLOSEDATE] = CONVERT(datetime, '1900-01-01')
            )
```

Comment: Thank you, your addition did the trick.  I seemed to have tried everything but your now obvious solution.  I tested the output and also looked at records filtered out and have full confidence. I still have some fine tuning with tasks scheduled by week, month quarter, annual, to find what open tasks are missing, but that is now quite doable.

Comment: I'm glad that I could be of help. If you feel like that's the right answer, please consider accepting it.